# Inkscape python-lxml error

Tags: python, inkscape

I'm using Inkscape 0.91 (r13725) and I always receive this error message when I try to use Perspective add-on or when I try to save the sketch in any format:

```
The fantastic lxml wrapper for libxml2 is required by inkex.py and therefore this extension. 
Please download and install the latest version from http://cheeseshop.python.org/pypi/lxml/, or install it through your package manager by a command like: sudo apt-get install python-lxml
Technical details: No module named lxml
```

And I've already installed the python-lxml package and nothing happened.

Can anyone help me?
Thanks for the answers!

Comment: A similar question has been asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27008222/importerror-no-module-named-lxml-even-though-lxml-is-installed).

Comment: @usmanayubsh That's for Mac OS

Answer (score 5):

Dávid Bartal, I have had the same problem.

Since I installed a package named "python2-lxml", things work normally.

Tip: Inkscape uses python 2.x instead of python 3.x, so install python2 compatible modules. For example install python2-lxml instead of python-lxml.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks so much, this error was driving me nuts, your solution fixed it nicely.

Answer (score 0):

**I fixed it!**

> The fantastic lxml wrapper for libxml2 is required by inkex.py and therefore this extension.Please download and install the latest version from http://cheeseshop.python.org/pypi/lxml/, or install it through your package manager by a command like: sudo apt-get install python-lxml
>   Technical details:
>   No module named lxml

I was trying to save an Inkscape 0.92.1 file when I got this error. I needed to run:

`brew install libxml2` followed by

`easy_install lxml`

After this I got another error:

> Failed to import Python module 'scour'.
>   Please make sure it is installed (e.g. using 'pip install scour' or 'sudo apt-get install python-scour') and try again.
>   Details:
>   No module named scour

which I fixed by running:

`easy_install scour`

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: It does not. What is easy_install?

Comment: This answer relies on python-centered package installation, which may depend on other packages and install a version different from what was tested by Ubuntu. In an ideal world, it's okay and sometimes it works. That said, when distribution, like here, provides in its native package format an up-to-date enough precompiled package, using that avoids running into troubles (or complications intended to avoid troubles, like python `virtualenv` etc). That's what @IvanGut answer does, and therefore is preferred. In other cases, besides `brew install` `pip install` is also possible. Keep it simple.